# How to log stdin stdout of a process/commandline tool?

Tags: c, linux

I am modifying a commandline tool that is interactive (like ftp ) How Can I write a thread that logs all stdin and stdout so the thread doesnt block the process (async) ?

thx.

Comment: you can redirect stdout to a file, via dup2(2) and open(2), stdin, not sure what you mean, you can just log that to a file too

Comment: what about stdin ?

Comment: u can also dup2 stdin, but what would be the point?

Comment: just security/logging activity of like ftp

Comment: there are questions for c++ but not for C/dup

Comment: Why not just use `tee input.txt | ./myprogram | tee output.txt`

Comment: cant use tee. It needs to be a C code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761950/how-can-i-implement-tee-programmatically-in-c  is a process not a thread

Comment: Why not use the `script` command to make a transcript of your session?

Comment: You probably need to look at pseudo-ttys (ptys).  These are what `expect` uses, for example, to fool the program into thinking it is connected to a terminal, so that output is not unreasonably buffered, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is there any examples of running ptys in a thread to log stdin and stdout ?

Comment: Have you tried searching among the 200+ questions tagged [tag:pty] on SO?